# Exception while printing inside a try block

Tags: python, python-3.x

I  am trying to print the user ID (int type) and name(varchar type) inside a try block. After enterint details on UID and name, while trying to print the entered value the except block is getting hit. If I remove the print statement from try block. It is working properly. Kindly suggest.

```
import mysql.connector
import sys

con = mysql.connector.connect(user='root',password='dream',host='localhost',port='3306',database='arvind')

cursor = con.cursor()
try:
    cursor.execute("create table USER_INFO(U_ID bigint,name varchar(20))")
except:
    print("table already created\n")
    #cursor.close()
    #con.close()
    #sys.exit();
print("table created successfully :)\n")

#cursor.close()
#con.close()

ch = input("Do you want to inseret data ??? (y/n)")
if ch=='y':
    while 1:
        try:
            num = int(input("Enter UID : "))
            #print("num entered ",num)
            name = input("Enter U_name : ")
            #print("name entered ",name)
            print("UID : ",UID,"\nname: ",name)
        except:
            print("Enter user ID for UID and name for U_name")
            continue;
        cursor.execute("""INSERT INTO USER_INFO values (%s,%s)""",(num,name))
        con.commit()
        print("Data inserted in the table")
        c = input("Enter 'n' top exit")
        print("c : ",c)
        if(c == 'n'):
            sys.exit();

else:
    print("NO")
```

Comment: Where do you define `UID`?

Comment: This is a perfect example of why you should **never** use a bare except.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code is trying to access the variable `UID` which is not defined:

```
print("UID : ",UID,"\nname: ",name)
               ^^^
```

The actual variable the code defined is `num`:

```
num = int(input("Enter UID : "))
```

Change either `UID` to `num` or `num` to `UID` according to your need.